# Parsing non-standard XML in SQL Server with XTbl

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a serialised piece of data in a column that I want to retrieve a single value from, in the following form:

```
<FirstNode>Something</><SecondNode>Something Else</>
```

I want to retrieve, for example, 'Something' from this in SQL Server. I've tried the following:

```
declare @data xml;
set @data = cast([my data source] as xml);

select @data.value('(/UserName)[1]','varchar(50)')
```

I'm probably way off with this, I don't have a huge deal of experience with parsing XML. Any help would be great.

Edit: I get the error

> XML parsing: line 1, character 20, illegal qualified name character

Comment: That's not XML, no compliant XML parser should accept it. Ask whomever is sending it to you to send XML instead, or you'll have to write your own not-XML parser.

Comment: Describing this as non-standard XML is a bit like describing Fortran as non-standard Java. Forget any notion of using XML tools to process non-XML. Don't even think of it as XML. If you want to ask questions about it, don't tag your questions as "XML".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING functions to get the data you want. Rolling my example into a function would probably be your best bet.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(data VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
    ('<FirstNode>Something</><SecondNode>Something Else</>'),
    ('<SecondNode>Something Else</><FirstNode>More Something</>'),
    ('<BadNoe>Something</><SecondNode>Something Else</>')

DECLARE @fnd VARCHAR(64)
DECLARE @end VARCHAR(64)
SET @fnd = '<FirstNode>'
SET @end = '</>'

SELECT SUBSTRING(a.[data], a.[start] + LEN(@fnd), a.[end] - (a.[start] + LEN(@fnd)))
FROM (SELECT data [data], CHARINDEX(@fnd, data, 0) [start], CHARINDEX(@end, data, CHARINDEX(@fnd, data, 0)) [end] FROM @tbl) a
WHERE a.[start] > 0
```

Comment: After I realised there was no way XML parsing would work, this seemed like the next best thing. Nice clean solution, thanks.

Comment: @Dan - Just a note, this solution will fall apart if you have nested elements <a><b>1</><c>2</></> finding 'a' would return <b>1</> instead of <b>1</><c>2</>